# Change variable data using different function in controller using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

As you can see i declared a variable `$tabname` with an empty value in the `function accountsettings()`. Once the user submitted the form in my view file it will go to the `function changepassword()`. I am trying to change the value of the `$tabname` after the user submitted the form.

```
public function accountsettings()
    {
        $tabname = " ";
        return view('account_settings')->with("tabName", $tabname);
    }

 public function changepassword(Request $request, $id)
    {

        // $this->validate($request, [
        // 'newPassword' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        // ]);

        $user = Auth::user();

        $tabname = "password";

        $curPassword = $request->post('oldPassword');
        $newPassword = $request->post('newPassword');

        if (Hash::check($curPassword, $user->password)) {
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $obj_user = User::find($user_id)->first();
            $obj_user->password = Hash::make($newPassword);


        }
        else
        {

        }
           return redirect()->route('account_settings')->with("tabName", $tabname);

    }
```

i have multiple tabs in my view.. what i want is once the user submitted the form inside a particular tab, it will remain on that tab after the page is loaded. i added this code in my view `class="nav-link {{ empty($tabName) || $tabName == 'password' ? 'active' : '' }}"` that is why i am the changing the value of the $tabname once the user submitted the form. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does not seem to work ?

Comment: `accountsettings()` will always return an "empty" `$tabname`. Do you have to set the tabname in a controller action? Wouldn't it be easier to do in your view?

Comment: i have multiple tabs in my view.. what i want is once the user submitted the form inside a particular tab, it will remain on that tab after the page is loaded. i added this code in my view `class="nav-link {{ empty($tabName) || $tabName == 'password' ? 'active' : '' }}"` that is why i am the changing the value of the $tabname once the user submitted the form.